# How to get constraints from UIView Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want get UILabel constraints from UIView but I can't get any constraints.
I set the constraints in CustomView.m like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         _titleLabel = [UILabel new];
         [self addSubview:_titleLabel];
     }
     return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     _titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     NSLayoutConstraint *titleLabelBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_titleLabel
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:0];
     [self addConstraints:@[titleLabelBottom]];

     ...more code

}
```

in ViewController.m

```
 CustomView *view = [CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
 NSLog(@"%@",view.titleLabel.constraints); // nil
```

Comment: `layoutSubviews:` is called many times, and you always create a new constraint. Move the constraint creation to your initializer

Answer (score 2):

you can get constraints in `NSArray` like,

```
NSArray *constraintArr = self.backButton.constraints;
NSLog(@"cons : %@",constraintArr);
```

And you can set instance variable like,

```
NSLayoutConstraint *titleLabelBottom;
```

and then use,

```
titleLabelBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_titleLabel
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:self
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                         multiplier:1
                                           constant:0];
[self addConstraints:@[titleLabelBottom]];
```

so, you can use `titleLabelBottom` anywhere in class.

hope this will help :)

Comment: it returns the constraints which are placed inside this view only. For example if you have constraint ```height = 0.5*superview.height``` - you won't see it in this array

Answer (score 1):

You are getting nil because the constraint has not been created yet.

Try logging your constraints in:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;
```

Assumming that constraint is essential to your CustomView, you should create that constraint in your initWithFrame method method.