# Is there any way to get all the applied Auto-layout constrains programatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I want to get the reference of all applied constraint using storyboard without any reference:

I had tried many ways but could not able to find the exact solution:

My Approach is as follows:

```
    if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height}.first) {

}
```

using the above approach, I am able to find out the height only.

```
if let topConstraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .top}.first) {
            topConstraint.constant = 150//topMargin
        }
if let leadingConstraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .leading}.first) {
            leadingConstraint.constant = 60 //leadingMargin
        }
```

For topConstraint and leadingConstraint i am getting nil.

```
self.constraints
```

self.constraints is giving only one reference that is height only even I had applied leading, trailing and bottom constraint on the same view.

**Note: I don't want to take reference from storyboard so please don't suggest that solution. I want reference dynamically.**

I am looking for the approach something like below:

```
 if let topConstraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .top}.first) {
                topConstraint.constant = 150//topMargin
            }
   if let leadingConstraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .leading}.first) {
                leadingConstraint.constant = 60 //leadingMargin
            }
   if let trailingConstraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .trailing}.first) {
                trailingConstraint.constant = 70//leadingMargin
            }
   if let bottomConstraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .bottom}.first) {
                bottomConstraint.constant = 150//49 + bottomMargin
            }
```

But unfortunately above one is not working for me :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get constraints from UIView Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641487/how-to-get-constraints-from-uiview-programmatically)

Comment: @bhatejaudI have applied my constraint using storyboard and want to access reference of that at runtime. Both questions are different. 
Please suggest me if you have any solution.

Comment: @Alok i think you can get constraints by identifier. here is the link apple document 
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526879-identifier

Comment: Hmm... actually, your questions leads me to say: what's your purpose of doing this?! i.e what's the general issue?

Comment: @chiragshah thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to follow this approach because I have more than 50 controllers and want to change everywhere. So this approach will lead the runtime bugs.

Do you have any approach like given in quesitons for the height?

if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height}.first) {

}

Comment: @AhmadF i have 50 controllers and controller have tableview so i want to change all tableviews leadiing, trailing,top and bottom constraint in single file using subclassing.

Comment: @Alok then why not have the constraints in a variable in the subclass? You can later access the variable of that that particular object as required.

Comment: @Alok - if you want to change constraints of all tableviews in many controllers than use NSNotificationCenter and add observers in different controllers. Create objects of required constraints and on post notification change these constraint values. And if you want another approach than read my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Please read the last sentence in my question. I had updated my question for you :)

Comment: @SmitShah using NSNotificationCenter is not a good approach. I am not looking for Jugad. I am looking for best Approach.

Comment: Its not a Jugad. How will you change UI in all viewcontrollers?. NSNotificationCenter is being used for this

Comment: So far I am unable to reproduce your issue (`constraints` array gives me all constraints), could you mention where are you using these code snippets? also, you mentioned that it is `self.constraints`, which means that its *not* a view controller (because it would be `view.constraints` instead).

Comment: @AhmadF I have created subclass like
class CardTitle: UILabel{
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    }
}

And assigning this class to view in a storyboard.

Comment: Well... could you check the value of `view.constraints` in the view controller itself (`viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` methods)?

Comment: @AhmadF in viewdidLoad also not getting constraint but I have cross-checked my constraint on the storyboard and all are there.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For a single view you can easily get all the constraints related to it

```
for constraint in view.constraints {
   print(constraint.constant)
}
```

And for all the subviews of a particular view, you can get like this

```
func getAllTheConstraintConstantsFor(view:UIView) {

   for constraint in view.constraints {
      print(constraint.constant)
   }

   for subview in view.subviews {
      self.getAllTheConstraintConstantsFor(view: subview)
   }
}
```

Here you can pass self.view and you will get all the constraints.

Comment: self.constraints giving only height. I have already explained in my question.

Comment: I have not set height constraint to any view and I am getting all the leading and trailing constraints also

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26833710) answer

For a view like `UIButton` you can find `top` constraint by using this code.

```
extension UIButton {

    func findTopConstraint() -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        for constraint in (self.superview?.constraints)! {
            if isTopConstraint(constraint: constraint) {
                return constraint
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func isTopConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool {
        return (firstItemMatchesTopConstraint(constraint: constraint) || secondItemMatchesTopConstraint(constraint: constraint))
    }

    func firstItemMatchesTopConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool {
        return (constraint.firstItem as? UIButton == self && constraint.firstAttribute == .top )
    }

    func secondItemMatchesTopConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool {
        return (constraint.secondItem as? UIButton  == self && constraint.secondAttribute == .top)
    }
}
```

To get `top` constaint on `UIButton` just use this code

```
button.findTopConstraint()!
```

Similarly you can find any constraint on any view.

Note : You need to manage `nil` case yourself.

Comment: @sunnyI am getting view.constraints equal zero even I had applied constraints on the same view using storyboard.

Comment: @Alok you mentioned you are getting height constraint.

Comment: I don't know what's happening in my code. For some of the view, I am getting only height constraint and for other views always getting zero.
Please see my another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52272096/3024579

Comment: using `view.constraint` you will get only width or height on a view

Comment: You will not get constraint which are related to superview.

Comment: ooh got your point. Is there any other way to get all the constraint of view?

Comment: Use the code in answer. I have tried it and i am getting `topConstraint`.

Comment: view don't have any property name as topConstraint. Are you talking about topAnchor?

Comment: It is `top` not topconstraint . It is an `attribute` of `NSLayoutAttribute`