# Constrains count is always getting zero ( 0 ) in AutoLayout - iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I am getting one weird issue, I am setting constraints on the view using storyboard as below:
[image]

But if I am accessing all applied constraint by code then always getting zero (0).

[image]

for self.view it's returning the constraint but for yellow view getting zero.

Comment: The constraints are set on the superview. Only descendants' and self referring constraints (like width, height, aspect ratio) would be set on `subView`

Comment: @MihaiFratu is there any other way to get all the constraint?

Comment: See @SAXENA answer. It should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this code (Swift 4+ and Xcode 9.4.1)**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var subView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(self.view.getAllConstraints().count)
    print(self.subView.getAllConstraints().count)
  }
}

extension UIView {

func getAllConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    var views = [self]
    var view = self
    while let superview = view.superview {
        views.append(superview)
        view = superview
    }
    return views.flatMap({ $0.constraints }).filter { constraint in
        return constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self ||
            constraint.secondItem as? UIView == self
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for your information when viewDidLoad is called subviews is not laid out yet thats why you getting count zero put you code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you will get your constraints there

[image: Demo]

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews in this metthod also I am getting 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to print constraints in `viewDidAppear`. In `viewDidLoad` method constraints not loaded for view so, just try in `viewDidAppear` method.